# New to Javascript, could someone help me with this substring problem?

Tags: javascript, html, substring

The below script returns the following into my html:

"3.9 °C {alarm,unackedAlarm}"

I would like to remove the "{alarm,unackedAlarm}" section so it just shows the temperature value. I believe I need to use a substring to achieve this but I cannot work out where to place it?

Thanks

```
  <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js" ></script>
require(['baja!', 'dialogs'], function (baja, dialogs) {
  
var sub = new baja.Subscriber();

sub.attach('changed', function(prop) {
  if(prop.getName() === 'value');

 {
    document.getElementById("oat").innerHTML = ( this.get(prop));
  }
});
baja.Ord.make('station:|slot:/BajaScriptExamples/Components/Ramp/out/value').get({ subscriber: sub});
});
```

'''

Comment: Get the index of the "{" in the string and subtract 1 to include the previous space character, e.g. `str.substring(0, str.indexOf('{') - 1)` where *str* is "3.9 °C {alarm,unackedAlarm}".

Comment: if the string after the temperature is always {alarm, unacked alarm} then you could use a string replace function to replace that string with nothing. Assign the prop value to a var and then replace e.g.var temp = str.replace("{alarm,unackedAlarm}", "");  .. and then output that value to wherever you wanna show it.. No need for finding the index if the additional string has a constant value, if it hasn't , well then this solution wouldn't work ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the regex approach just in case the number of characters change.

```js
function extract(text) {
  const pattern = /^(.*) {.*}$/g;
  const match = [...text.matchAll(pattern)];
  if (match.length == 0 || match[0].length == 0) {
    console.error("text does not match");
    return;
  }
  return match[0][1];
}

console.log(extract("3.9 °C {alarm,unackedAlarm}"));
```

The main idea here is to **catch** any string that follows this pattern `(.*) {.*}` and return what is in contained between the parenthesis (group).

Answer (score 0):

The requirement of extracting specific part of a string can be done easily by using the `split()` function of Javascript.

**Here are working examples using split:**

**Example 1:  Split the string at blank spaces and print the first two parts.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            var str = "3.9 °C {alarm,unackedAlarm}"
            var result = str.split(" ")
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (result[0] + " " + result[1])
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**Example 2:  Split the string at '{' and print the first part.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script>
            var str = "3.9 °C {alarm,unackedAlarm}"
            var result = str.split("{")
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (result[0].trim())
        </script>  
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
3.9 °C
```

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp